# Alias xdg-open to open

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

Is there a way to change the command `xdg-open` to the more simple `open`? Including the ability to pass a path to it? For example, instead of typing `xdg-open .`, I'd like to simply type `open .`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can alias anything you like (but check that the command you want to use doesn't already exist first: `type open` should tell you `not found`) Make a backup of your `~/.bashrc` and define the alias:

```
cp .bashrc bashrc-bak
nano .bashrc
```

Add at the end

```
alias open='xdg-open'
```

Or if you want to avoid seeing any warnings from the program that is called, discard output with a redirection as [suggested by TalkLittle](https://askubuntu.com/questions/808053/alias-xdg-open-to-open/808057?noredirect=1#comment1308356_808057):

```
alias open='xdg-open &>/dev/null'
```

Save and exit, then type `source .bashrc` to use the alias immediately. The alias will take arguments just like the full command, of course.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not terribly great with bash commands just yet, so I appreciate the help :)

Comment: @Rev more than welcome :)

Comment: Use `alias open='xdg-open &>/dev/null'` to hide Nautilus errors when typing `open .`

Comment: @zanna could you integrate TalkLittle's tip in your answer ?  It makes for an even cleaner solution and this is what I was looking for that drove me to this thread. Anyways thanks to both of you !

Comment: @NicolasMarshall done, thank you for the suggestion :)